# Conditional Format if cell contains partial match for text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I want to conditional format the columns `B` to `G`, if one of them contains the text in say, cell `H5`.
This is the formula I use for that, `=$H$5=B1` at the moment.

**What I want is for the conditional format to work even if its a partial match**. E.g. if I search for 'eggs', and a cell has the text 'boiled eggs' that should get highlighted too.
I've used the match function before in this manner `=MATCH("*text*",G1,0)'` so it searches for partial matches. And what I want is for it to conditional format if the text in `H5` is a complete match or even a partial match.
So the formula would be something like `=match("*H5*"...)`

Basically its like the cell is a Google search bar.

Pls see the Inventory tab. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rlATwRPTkofEg0rB5-GSwwBpQDa7ZOoeNvhs0xPOsKA/edit#gid=0

This the formula I use at the moment for exact matches
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following formula in `Custom formula is`

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("*"&INDIRECT("H5")&"*",B2,0)>0,true,),false)
```

[image]

Comment: No sorry, that's not what I want actually. 

I want to enter the name into a cell, & conditional format picks up that value and runs to formula to highlight the cells. So its like in place of the *eggs*, I want the cell reference, so it picks up whichever text is in the cell & matches, partial or full match. The cell should act like a search bar.

Comment: Aha... I misunderstood your question. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: A very useful and clever conditional formatting case. Well thought. To take it a step further. Cell `H5` could be a drop down with your ingredients through data validation.

Comment: Thank you so much AGAIN! Now I'll be googling to breakdown you solution to find out how it works :D

Comment: I'll trade my secrets for recipes. Deal? :)

Comment: Hahaha sure. But I'm not the one making the recipes though. :D